# как в Ajax запрос в laravel?

Tags: laravel

как передать в url: "", нужный мне роут с методом?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте `{{ route('your_route', ['id' => 1]) }}` в шаблоне.

Answer (score 0):

если вы разделяете код шаблона и javascript то рекомендуется использовать атрибут data для ссылки и получать его в скрипте

Шаблон

```
<button type="button" id="js-button" data-url="{{ route('you_route') }}">Action</button>
```

Javascript

```
$('#js-button').click(function(){
    $.post($(this).data('url'))
        .done(function(response){})
        .fail(function(){})
});
```

Comment: точно, так и сделал